# Specify template applicationhost.config when launching iis express

Tags: iis-express

When launching iisexpress using `iisexpress /path:D:\Foo /port:9000` how can I specify what file it uses as the template applicationhost.config file?

Currently it uses, `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config` but I need to use a different one so that I can unlock/customize various sections.

I would prefer not to have to set each site up in `~/Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no option to provide custom template applicationhost.config file.

what is the issue in editing `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config` itself and doing your customizations?

If you don't want to edit that file, then you can make a copy of applicationhost.config at desired location and edit site information (path and port information ) and finally use '/config' command line switch as follows

```
iisexpress /config:<full-path-to-custom-applicationhost.config>
```

Comment: I didn't want to have to use administrative rights to alter the config file, and any changes to the standard template would affect every site. Copying seems a simple option at the disadvantage of having to manually set up each site in the config. Another interesting idea would be to use the web.config transformations and a powershell script to alter the standard template, merge in the site settings and launch iisexpress with the temporary config file.